# Django Rest Frame API: additional fields in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can I add additional fields to ModelSerializer subclass?

By saying 'additional field', I mean some fields don't belong any models in database, which any effort that try to map those fields to exist model fields will fail. The reason I need to include those fields is for design purpose. I need to those fields' value to do the validation and creating a new instance eventually.

I know there is a kwarg in ModelSerialzer called 'context'. By putting all the additional information into 'context', it will work. However, I want to know is that possible to create additional fields?

I have tried adding 'write_only=True', which doesn't work. The only left option is to override default restore_object method to create the instance with my will.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not posted any code I can only give you a generic answer, but if I understand you correctly, you wish to add a custom field to a ModelSerializer thats not part of your model...

In DSF you can do this very esaily ([read here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-fields-explicitly)):

In this case you just want a simple read-only field, so instead just use:

```
custom_field = Field(source='get_whatever')
```

In terms if validation after that please read the DRF guide [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#validation)